# Mac Cocoa app GUI freezing while Process running

Tags: swift, multithreading, cocoa, xcode9, freeze

I've made a basic Mac OS X Cocoa application with Swift in Xcode 9. The app gathers a source and a destination from the user, and then transfers the data from source to destination. The data transfer is done by launching an rsync script as a Process:

```
let path = "/bin/bash"
let arguments = ["/path/to/backup.sh", sourcePath, destinationPath]
task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments as! [String])
```

The problem is that, while the transfer is running, the app gets the spinning rainbow wheel and the GUI can't be used. This makes a 'Cancel' button or a functional progress bar impossible.

Once the transfer finishes, the app becomes functional again, and any test output (e.g., print statements, progress bar) goes through (instead of going through while the backup was running like it was supposed to).

I thought threads might help resolve this issue, so I looked into this post about threads from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

However, the code in the article doesn't seem to have correct syntax in Xcode, so I'm not sure how to continue with threads.

I'm at a dead end, any help would be appreciated!

After running the app, pausing in the debugger, and typing 'bt' in the debugger console, this is the output:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
frame #0: 0x00007fff65fc120a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x00007fff65fc0724 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 60
frame #2: 0x00007fff3dac4045 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
frame #3: 0x00007fff3dac3397 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1783
frame #4: 0x00007fff3dac2a07 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
frame #5: 0x00007fff3cda0d96 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
frame #6: 0x00007fff3cda0b06 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
frame #7: 0x00007fff3cda0884 HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
frame #8: 0x00007fff3b053a73 AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 2085
frame #9: 0x00007fff3b7e9e34 AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
frame #10: 0x00007fff3b048885 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 764
frame #11: 0x00007fff3b017a72 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 804
* frame #12: 0x000000010000a88d Mac Syncy`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
frame #13: 0x00007fff65e7a015 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
frame #14: 0x00007fff65e7a015 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Is there any further code referencing `task` in your program? Launching a process shouldn't hang the application on its own.

Comment: Where do you run the task? Your code only shows how you _create_ the instance (btw. by a deprecated API; you should use `init()`), not how it get's started.

Comment: @duskwuff nope there are no other references to the `task` variable. I had tried launching with `task?.waitUntilExit()` but that does the same thing. I also tried doing some testing with `while task?.isRunning` but we're unable to do anything with that. It's like the program can't see that `task` is running.

Comment: While the program is stuck, pause it in the debugger and look at the stack of the main thread. That will show you where it's stuck, which usually helps you figure out why it's stuck.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen the `Process.launchedProcess` part is starting the Process. I'm not entirely sure how it works, I found it online. How do I start a Process using `init()`?

Comment: @KenThomases OK I just tried that. When I pause it in the debugger, I see the stop signal, but it doesn't actually stop the process. It might be because it's using rsync, which would normally have to be paused/stopped through Terminal. Even if I quit the app, the transfer continues. 

Also, after pausing it in the debugger, the app is still frozen. The assembly code stack stops shortly after the signal, and there's nothing to indicate where the app is getting frozen. Everything looks normal, besides the signal.

Comment: Well, uh, when it's paused in the debugger, yes, the app is "frozen". That much is normal. Also, of course, the separate rsync process continues. To figure out what's going on, be sure to select the main thread in Xcode's thread list in the Debug navigator. Then, in the debug console pane, at the "(lldb)" prompt, type "bt" and return. Edit your question and paste the resulting text into it.

Comment: @KenThomases right, I'm just saying that the app is still getting the rainbow wheel regardless of whether it is paused in the debugger or not. Also, I followed your instructions and edited the question.

Comment: You paused the app while it was showing the spinning cursor? That stack trace looks like the main thread is idle and ready to handle input.

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, I paused it while it was showing the spinning cursor. I guess it had to do with how I was starting the Process. Andreas showed me how to start it with `init()` and now it works! Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found out several things:

1. In fact, `launchedProcess` causes the process to be launched immediately. Instead, use `init` to gain more control
2. If you call `waitForExit`, then the current thread will wait until the end of the process.
3. When you launch an process, this will run independently from your App. So if you quit your app, the launched process still continues running.

So let' start (completely working view controller at the very end):

### 1. Creating the Process

```
task = Process.init()
task.launchPath = path
task.arguments = arguments
task.currentDirectoryPath = workDir
// not running yet, so let's start it:
task.lauch()
```

### 2. Wait for the end of child process asynchronously

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print ("wating for exit")
    self.task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

### 3. Kill child process

You'll have to terminate the task e.g. in `applicationWillTerminate` in the application delegate.

Nevertheless, you should be aware that this could lead your (rsync) operation to stay in an undeterminated state - file/directorys only being half-copied etc.

### 4. Bonus: Progress indicator

I think the only way to provide a progress indicator is to parse the output of the Process (`task.standardOutput`) and check wheather rsync provides useful information here. But this is a completly new story, so no code here, sorry.

### The code

This is a view controller with a start and a cancel button.
Keep in mind, that for a shipped application, you'll have to provide more error checking.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var task:Process!
    var out:FileHandle?
    var outputTimer: Timer?


    @IBAction func startPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("** starting **")

        let path = "/bin/bash"
        let workDir = "/path/to/working/folder"
        let sourcePath = "source"
        let destinationPath = "destination"

        let arguments = ["backup.sh", sourcePath, destinationPath]
        task = Process.init()
        task.launchPath = path
        task.arguments = arguments
        task.currentDirectoryPath = workDir

        self.task.launch()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            // this runs in a worker thread, so the UI remains responsive
            print ("wating for exit")
            self.task.waitUntilExit()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // do so in the main thread
                if let timer = self.outputTimer {
                    timer.invalidate()
                    self.outputTimer = nil
                }
            }
        }

    }


    @IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("** cancelling **")
        if let timer = self.outputTimer {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.outputTimer = nil
        }
        task.interrupt()
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! You're a genius, thank you soo much!! The 'Cancel' button actually still doesn't stop the data transfer, but I'll figure that out. The most important thing was the app becoming unresponsive, which is now fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: This solved my problem with the UI being locked. My app calls a Python script which itself calls an API and wrapping that process in DispatchQueue.global().async and then the UI work in DispatchQueue.main.async did the trick!